# AWS deployment: Jenkins + AWS CodeDeploy vs Jenkins + commands over SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-deployment, aws-code-deploy

I would like to know what would be a better approach to deploying code to an AWS EC2 instance.

At my workplace we have a project where the Jenkins job for deploying would go (1):

- pull the code on the Jenkins machine
- zip it and upload to an S3 instance
- CodeDeploy downloads and unpacks the code to the EC2 instance
- runs migrations, builds assets, restarts server etc.

And on the other it would go (2):

- Jenkins SSH's to the EC2 instance
- git pulls from the production branch / release tag
- runs migrations, builds assets, restarts server etc.

The second scenario looks much simpler than the first, even though I more often see the first one, or a variation of it.
And I can see that the first one would be better for running tests before the actual deploy, but other than that I don't see much advantage in it.

In your experience, which one would be better (omitting the testing part)?
Are there any glaring security issues with any of them that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

The first approach which uses code deploy means that you have many deployment configurations available to you.

This can either be for application related changes or infrastructure ones.

As you mentioned, artefacts of the applications to be deployed are uploaded to S3 and CodeDeploy does the rest depending on the deployment configuration. This gives you flexibility to roll back changes etc automatically.

In addition, i believe ssh access is not required when working with infrastructures that are linked to CodeDeploy, so this reduces some maintenance and security issues related to the keys etc.

From the infrastructure side. It is relatively easy to construct some load balanced infrastructure (ELB + ASG) in AWS and link it to CodeDeploy. The agent is all that is required. However, if you need to adjust the infrastructure, that is, scale out or up. Those changes can be introduced relatively easily via CodeDeploy and its deployment configurations.

In addition, from the S3 bucket, rather than going directly to CodeDeploy you could incorporate a CodePipeline made up of deploy stages which deploy to different environments connected to CodeDeploy. Meaning that perhaps some testing tasks ran by Jenkins could be delegated to CodeDeploy or a stage in a CodePipeline which leads to the final CodeDeploy stage.

These are just the reasons why in my opinion the first option is better. So to summarise, I think the first option is strategically more useful in the long run assuming your requirements might change. By leveraging CodeDeploy you can adapt and expand your approach later on.

Hope this helps!
Patrick